# postgresql - how and why indexes are bigger than their tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm using postgresql 9.3 and trying to understand how and why indexes are bigger than their tables.

Sample output:

```
 database_name | database_size |                          table_name                          | table_size | indexes_size | total_size
---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+------------
 foo_12345 | 412 MB        | "foobar_dev_12345"."fact_mobile_sends"                       | 57 MB      | 131 MB       | 189 MB
 foo_12345 | 412 MB        | "foobar_dev_12345"."fact_mobile_started"                      | 17 MB      | 39 MB        | 56 MB
 foo_12345 | 412 MB        | "foobar_dev_12345"."fact_mobile_stopped"                      | 16 MB      | 35 MB        | 51 MB
```

I'm running the following query to get the table and index sizes.

```
SELECT
    table_catalog AS database_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database())) As database_size,
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) AS indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_catalog,
        pg_database_size(current_database()) AS database_size,
        table_name,
        pg_table_size(table_name) AS table_size,
        pg_indexes_size(table_name) AS indexes_size,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name, table_catalog
        FROM information_schema.tables
    ) AS all_tables
    ORDER BY total_size DESC
) AS pretty_sizes;
```

Is my query correct? What would cause indexes to be bigger?

Comment: My guess is that you have a table where the individual row size is small, there are many row entries, and there are multiple indexes on the table.  This would easily lead to the case you are seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- Numerous and probably overlapping indexes on the table; have a look with `\d`
- Bloat due to high update churn can sometimes affect indexes more than tables, depending on update patterns. Examine the size of each individual index to see if it makes sense.
- GiST indexes, if used, can be quite large

Unlike what I originally thought this is *not* an issue with `TOAST` out-of-line storage not being counted, since `pg_table_size` includes `TOAST` tables.

Note that if you're concerned about index bloat and decide to `REINDEX` some of all of the involved indexes, consider setting a non-default `FILLFACTOR` first if the table is subject to lots of updates (or inserts+deletes). Otherwise you'll take a write performance hit because the index doesn't have any space to insert new values so it'll force lots of page splits and be less efficiently structured.